# MultiThreading in javaMail with Kotlin

Tags: android, email, kotlin, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to build an email client app via javaMail with Kotlin. I used doAsync for multiThreading. But I have some problem. Getting data through the IMAP protocol is okay. When I put data into cardView, it has a problem. I used doAsync again in OnBindViewHolder to get data from javax.Message type. That was slow and not show full data into card View.  -> Help me <--

This is adapter

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint

import android.content.Context

import android.view.LayoutInflater

import android.view.View

import android.view.View.*

import android.view.ViewGroup

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

import g2sysnet.smart_gw.R

import g2sysnet.smart_gw.inters.EventChanger

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.mail_reciever_row.view.*

import org.jetbrains.anko.custom.async

import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import javax.mail.Message

import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

class testAdapter (val context : Context, val receiveMessage : Array<Message> ,val eventChange : EventChanger):
RecyclerView.Adapter<testAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder : ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val message = receiveMessage[position]

        /** visibility **/
        holder.itemView.d3p.visibility = INVISIBLE
        holder.itemView.imV_attach.visibility = INVISIBLE
    doAsync{
        val from = message.from[0].toString().split("<")[0]
        val subject = message.subject
        val receivedDate = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd").format(message.receivedDate)
        val content = message.content.toString()
        val seen = message.flags.toString()

        /** unchangeable **/
        holder.itemView.dateTime.text = receivedDate
        holder.itemView.mailSender.text = from
        holder.itemView.subjectTxt.text = subject
        holder.itemView.bodyTxt.text = content
        when (seen) {
            "\\Seen" -> {
                holder.itemView.d3p.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
            "\\Flagged" -> {
                holder.itemView.star.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        context,
                        R.drawable.ic_star_border
                    )
                )
                holder.itemView.star.setColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        context,
                        R.color.icon_tint_selected
                    )
                )
            }
            "\\Flagged \\Seen" -> {
                holder.itemView.star.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        context,
                        R.drawable.ic_star_border
                    )
                )
                holder.itemView.star.setColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        context,
                        R.color.icon_tint_selected
                    )
                )
                holder.itemView.d3p.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
            "" -> {
                holder.itemView.d3p.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                holder.itemView.star.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        context,
                        R.drawable.ic_star_border
                    )
                )
                holder.itemView.star.setColorFilter(
                    ContextCompat.getColor(
                        context,
                        R.color.icon_tint_normal
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        notifyItemChanged(position)
        eventChange.change(position)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mail_reciever_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

class ViewHolder(itemView : View) :  RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return receiveMessage.size
}
}
```

this is main page

```
class MailBox : AppCompatActivity(),EventChanger, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


var adapter : mailReceiveAdapter? = null
override fun change(id: Int) {

    H.curRow = id
    startActivity(Intent(this@MailBox,ViewerActivity::class.java))
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mailbox)

    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.mailBoxToolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar?.title = "Mail List"

    allMail_recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MailBox)

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,
        drawerLayout,
        toolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    )
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this@MailBox)

    test()
}
fun test(){
    val dialog = ProgressDialog(this@MailBox)
    dialog.setCancelable(false)
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...")
    dialog.show()
    doAsync {
        val props = Properties()
        props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true")
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "143")
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true")
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", "993")

        val session =
            Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator(H.currentUser!!.DC_EMAIL, H.currentUser!!.NO_MAILPWD))
        val store = session.getStore("imaps")
        store.connect(H.currentUser!!.DC_MAILSERVER, H.currentUser!!.DC_EMAIL, H.currentUser!!.NO_MAILPWD)
        val emailFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox")
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY)
        val messages: Array<Message> = emailFolder.messages

        activityUiThread {
            val adapter = testAdapter(this@MailBox,messages,this@MailBox)
            allMail_recycler.adapter = adapter
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
override fun onBackPressed() {
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

}
```

I face this

[cardView with multiThreading (doAsync)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHxtq.png)

Comment: I need a better description than "it has a problem".  What problem?  Is an exception thrown?  Are you getting the wrong data?  What's an example?